# Checking a value in a string array in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to see if there is a cleaner way to do this logic. I have a working sample:

[Same fiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VrqPso)

```
public static Boolean passwordchecker(string userName)
    {
        string[] group = new string[] { "a", "b" };
        if (group[0] == userName || group[1] == userName)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear which specific elements of the logic you're interested in, or what the specific requirements are.  Will there always be two strings, or could there be more?  How many more?  The naming here suggests that the elements in `group` will be coming most likely from a database table or some other dynamic source, and depending on the application there could be anywhere from a handful of users to tens or hundreds of millions.  These considerations should guide your design decisions.  Can you state the significant requirements?

Comment: If the parameter refers to a password, it should be char[] or byte[], *never* string.

Comment: I know I late to this game, but you call a method passwordChecker where you compare a username against predefined groups???? I mean what???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has three issues:

1. The name `passwordchecker`: good method names are almost always a *verb* because they *do* things. I’d use `CheckPassword` (the capitalisation follows standard C# naming conventions). And, while we’re talking about names: the variable name `group` does not describe what the variable does, and, as a consequence, it took me unnecessary time to understand what your code is supposed to do. And, lastly, the parameter you call `userName` isn’t a user name; it’s a password, isn’t it? If so, you need to fix it. If it’s correct, you need to fix your method name because apparently it checks user names, not passwords.
2. The code uses the anti-pattern `if (expr) return true; else return false;`. This simply never makes sense, and it never makes for clearer code when compared to the alternative: `return expr;`. In fact, outside of direct variable initialisation, there’s virtually no use for the literals `true` and `false`.
3. There’s an array, but the code uses its values separately. As it stands, there is no reason for this to be an array (rather than separate variables), and it’s (very slightly) error-prone since a future maintainer might be tempted to extend the array, but forget to adjust its usage. [AlanT’s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274987) shows one way of checking whether a value can be found inside an array. Personally, I’d be tempted to use the `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains` method instead, because it doesn’t require using a predicate:

   ```
   public static bool CheckPassword(string password)
   {
       var passwords = new[] { "a", "b" };
       return passwords.Contains(password);
   }
   ```

   This requires `using System.Linq;`. Without that, you’ll have to cast the array explicitly to `IList<string>` because arrays only implement the `IList<T>` interface privately.

Furthermore, as shown in AlanT’s answer, I’d be tempted to make `passwords` a `private readonly static` variable rather than a local variable.

Comment: Downvoted for #3. A cast is a *last resort* in C#; you should almost never see it. Here you are doing it in order to get an interface you don't need (IList is for adding/removing) to use an uncommon method, instead of the simple, canonical `IEnumerable.Any`. Trying to avoid the predicate is anachronistic for no reason; modern C# uses Funcs and arrow functions.

Comment: @JounceCracklePop I really fail to see how `Any` is more canonical than `Contains`. Avoiding a predicate has nothing to do with anachronism: `Contains` is simply *the more appropriate method* here, and it’s less code (the cast adds code, but it’s at declaration, not use). At any rate the cast *is* used as a last resort here: it’s purely to work around an API issue: arrays should really implement `IList<T>` publicly.

Comment: The mental model of array is "contiguous block of memory". The mental model of `IList` is "an in-memory sequence that can be added to and removed from". It's an odd language idiosyncrasy if array implements `IList`. One of the designers of C# has stated that many things would be different if they had generics and `IEnumerable` from the start. Forcing a cast that only makes sense based on knowledge of a language idiosyncrasy to access a method on an interface *you don't want* is not your "last resort" when you can simply type `.Any` and explicitly control the comparison (as you should here).

Comment: @JounceCracklePop There’s more than one valid mental model, and the *relevant* mental model in this case is simply “sequence container”. The mental model you mention is correct but irrelevant, a pure implementation detail. We choose an array here merely because C# happens to provide a convenient construction syntax for arrays. You’re getting hung up on completely the wrong detail. If you dislike it, construct a `List<string>` instead of an array.

Comment: With `using System.Linq` you can avoid the cast, since [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0) exists. (For those micro-optimizers out there: Yes, the code of Enumerable.Contains is optimized to check for the `ICollection<T>` interface and just forward the call to `ICollection<T>.Contains`. Not that it matters for this use case...)

Comment: @Heinzi Of course, how could I forget that. Yes, that’s a much better solution.

Comment: If you have a collection that seldom changes and; you do not care about order, and the most common operation you will do against the collection is to check if an object is in the collection you should go for HashSet.

Comment: @Taemyr A HashSet makes sense if the collection has more than just a handful items. I don’t know where exactly the cut-off is, but it’s unlikely to be faster for a dozen items, and it’s definitely *slower* for only two or three. In fact, it’s a common optimisation to use flat arrays for tiny lookups. Beyond ~4 items you might want to sort them and use binary search but below that even binary search won’t speed things up. That said, my code isn’t concerned with optimisation but rather with *simplicity*. Keep it simple, unless this is a bottleneck.

Comment: True.  Although for two static items I would probably just write the comparison explicitly.

Answer (score 11):

Some of the naming seems off - it is a password checker but you are passing in and comparing a userName - but if you want a linq-ish solution you might try

```
private readonly static string[] Group = { "a", "b"};

private static bool PasswordChecker(string password)
{
    return Group.Any(g => g==password);
}
```

**Notes:**
I would generally make names of methods PascalCased in C# rather than all lower case.

Comment: Slightly shorter and slightly more readable: `Group.Contains(password)`

Comment: @Heinzi, Yes, that works better. The original version I had was doing case-insensitive comparisons (input was userName, which shouldn't be case sensitive). I changed back to match the original code I should have switched over to `Contains`

Comment: The inconsistent indentation could also be mentioned.

Comment: There is also *[Tools for format and error checking in your programming language](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/)*.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely some shorter/more performant ways to write that:

```
private static readonly string[] group = new string[] { "a", "b" };

public static bool passwordchecker(string userName) => group[0] == userName || group[1] == userName;
```

for example.

Comment: This is unlikely to be more performant.

Comment: Anything that uses an array will be less performant than just `username == "a" || username == "b"`

Comment: The array is not recreated (the GC'd) on every call to the method like the OP version. That is more performant.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest something closer to this:

A method's name should describe what it's doing.
When a method returns a bool, it's often best to start the method name with a verb like "is" so that it asks a question.

If statements should be used sparingly.
Else statements should be used even less.

```csharp
    public static bool IsUserNameValid(string userName) =>
        new List<string> { "a", "b" }
        .Any(value => string.Equals(value, userName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```